# Does NetBeans have any "collapse all" shortcut for open directories in the navigator view?

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

NetBeans has a helpful (to *me* anyway!) feature under the "Views" menu, called "Synchronize Editor with Views".  As the name suggests, toggling this on will cause the navigator view to jump straight to a file when it's opened in the editor.

I generally prefer this to the normal "Ctrl+Shift+1" shortcut for manually jumping to a file.  However, the downside is that after editing several files, your navigator tree is a mess of multiple open directories.

Eclipse has similar functionality, but it *also* has a "collapse all" button at the top of its navigator view... restoring things with a single click having to scroll around.  Does NetBeans have any similar mechanism for collapsing open directories?  Maybe a poorly-documented keyboard shortcut buried in there or something?

Comment: I think you all are talking about the Project panel, not the Navigator panel.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately, after further digging on the NetBeans discussion forums and mailing lists, it seems that this functionality simply doesn't exist.  That's a shame... hopefully they'll add it in the future.

Comment: Is there a bug in netbeans bugzilla to vote for?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, sorry.  Since posting this question last year, I've changed jobs.  My last company insisted on everyone using NetBeans, but my new company doesn't care which tools you use.  So I just went back to Eclipse, for the sake of various plugins.

Comment: Wow, what kind of company chooses IDE for you :D

Comment: @StevePerkins now there is a `collapse all` context menu since 7.2. That works for Project and File tabs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965200/netbeans-shortcut-key-for-collapsing-expanding-a-method but no keyboard short cut (yet).

Comment: See answer from Hardik and Daniel Rikowsky. Seems like the correct answer needs to be changed

Comment: Its 2015 and functionality is NOT yet added ! :)

Answer (score 64):

Unrelated to your question, but some interesting [code folding shortcuts](http://ui.netbeans.org/docs/ui/code_folding/cf_uispec.html) are:

| Action | Shortcut |
| --- | --- |
| Collapse Fold | Ctrl+Minus |
| Expand Fold | Ctrl+Plus |
| Collapse All Folds | Ctrl+Shift+Minus |
| Expand All Folds | Ctrl+Shift+Plus |

Comment: This is only for code folding, not for directories.

Comment: It collapses the project node itself but after expanding it, all the inner nodes (such as packages) are still expanded.  Too bad, Netbeans doesn't seem to have this feature.

Comment: This isn't an answer for the question, Steve Perkins answered his own question, mentioning that there is no support for CollapseAll (for the Projects/Navigator View, just like Visual Studio has one).

Comment: Not an answer for the question. Shut be down voted.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**: It is not possible.

**Workaround:** Close the project and reopen it. It will start collapsed.

Comment: This is like saying, a solution is to not ask the question.

Comment: A 'dirty' solution? We need a reasonably clean one.

Answer (score -2):

Close the navigator (press the x). Then go to Window->Navigating->Navigator or press Ctrl+7. It should open the navigator with all collapsed.

http://variousfixes.wordpress.com/2011/09/03/how-to-collapse-all-elements-in-netbeans-navigator/

Comment: This doesn't work. Closing and reopening keeps everything expanded just the way it was.